# ampl syntax error >>> x[ <<<

Tags: optimization, syntax-error, ampl

I am new to AMPL and can't seem to get past the following syntax error:

```
set I := {1, 2, 3, 4};
set J := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
set K := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

var d >=0;
var x binary;

CODE.txt, line 18 (offset 332):
    syntax error
context:  minimize Total_Cost: sum {i in I, j in J, k in K}  >>> x[ <<< i,j,k] * d[i];
```

I can't see why the error seemingly occurs at the square bracket as I thought that subscripts should always be defined within square brackets.

Any tips would be lovely!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, I found my mistake so will share it here in case anyone else encounters the same issue.

I merely forgot to specify the subscripts when initially stating the variable

Find below my modified (working) code:

```
set I := {1, 2, 3, 4};
set J := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
set K := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

var d{I} >=0;
var x{I,J,K} binary;

minimize Total_Cost: sum {i in I, j in J, k in K}  x[i,j,k] * d[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable you must to declare his indexes too. In your case the problem is in the "x".

You must write your model like this:

```
set I := {1, 2, 3, 4};
set J := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
set K := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

var d{i in I} integer >=0;
var x{i in I, j in J, k in K} binary;
```

Regards!